# How to add serveral deletion conditions on log4j2.properties?

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j2

We're using ElasticSearch 6.1.1

This is the default Rolling File on log4j2.properties:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.-10000m%n
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 1GB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
**appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.exceeds = 2GB**
```

There is just one Deletion condition, when the log files overcome 2GB space.

I want to add a second optional condition, when the log files overcome 7 days old.

I have applied next changes:

```
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.exceeds = 2GB
**appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.age = 7D**
```

But I'm doing something wrong because I'm not able to get the result I want.

Anyone could show me any example how to add two or more Deletion conditions on log4j2.properties?

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 8):

Try below configuration for `DeleteAction` -

```
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.fileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.fileSize.exceeds = 2GB
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.lastMod.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.lastMod.age = 7D
```

You can check some more examples in `log4j2` [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DeleteIfAccumulatedFileSize)

**NOTE:** The key line in this example is this one:

```
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.nested_condition.type = IfAny
```

This configures log4j2 to delete when any of the conditions is met (> 2GB or last modified 7D+).